# How to prevent scrolltop on some anchors?

Tags: anchor, scrolltop, anchor-scroll

Im using a pretty standard scrolltop snippet to run to certain parts on some of my pages but I also have some other functions that use anchors (ex. play button for audio player, share links, slider arrows)

Is there a way to improve the way the snippet handle anchors? Maybe a link with a special class or something?

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
var the_id = $(this).attr("href");
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop:$(the_id).offset().top - 100
}, 'slow');

return false;});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found out I just had to add the class/id to it changing

```
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
```

to

```
$('.your-class a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
```

yay me!